# How can i make this photos dynamic weight by code?

Tags: java, android, layout

I want that the pic will be dynamically like if I use this method 3 times it will give me 3 photos and the weight will be dynamic

```
public void addImageToRaw(final String text, final float rate/*, final TextView textView*/, final PhotosRatingInfo photosRatingInfo)
{
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView(rawLinear1.getContext());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(text));
            //imageView.setLayoutParams();
        //PhotosRatingInfo ratingInfo = new PhotosRatingInfo(rate, text);

        rawLinear1.addView(imageView, 150, 150);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //MainMenuActivity.Chasttext();

                RateDialog dialog = new RateDialog(text, rate/*, textView*/, photosRatingInfo);
                dialog.show(manager, "");

                //new RateDialog().show(manager, "");

            }
        });
}
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout.xml you can set a value for weight.  You can only do this for one row (you could just create as many seperate rows as you need.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Otherwise, if you really want a grid, you would need to use a GridView, but that requires Android OS 4.3+.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to achieve this would be using a GridView. That's the best way, as you get the same solution.